# Select Query using Column Alias Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have a query like :

```
Select table1.Name AS aliasname1, Count(aliasname1) as aliasname2 from table1.
```

But i am not sure if this query will execute successfully in sql because i have used alias name in same select statement .I need a solution for doing the same in sql.
I want solution as

```
aliasname1   aliasname2

Name1         4
Name2         4
Name3         4
Name4         4
```

Comment: Did you try it? No it won't work like that. You can't reference an alias within the same query.

Comment: **But i am not sure if this query will execute successfully** why you not sure ?

Comment: ya i have tried but it is giving me error "Invalid Column Name aliasname1" in sql.but i need a alternate solution for executing the same query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference an alias in your SELECT statement like that.  You are creating and attempting to call an alias at the same time, so the compiler doesn't know what the `aliasname1` is when you reference it in the same select statement.  So in order to fix this, you'd have to write the query the following way:

```
select 
  table1.Name AS aliasname1, 
  Count(table1.Name) as aliasname2 
from table1
```

Or if you want to reference an alias, you'll need to use a subquery:

```
select aliasname1,
  count(aliasname1) as aliasname2 
from 
(
  select table1.Name AS aliasname1
  from table1
) as d
```